# Postgres group by update - slow query

Tags: postgresql, group-by, aggregation

I am using postgres 9.X.
I have two tables

```
Table A
(
id integer
);

Table B
(
id integer,
Value integer
);
```

Both table are indexed on id.

Table A can have duplicate ID's

```
Example:
Table A
ID
1
1
1
2
1
```

I intend to insert number of occurrences of ID into table B (This table has all the ID's that are in Table A, but value is 0 initially)

```
Table B
ID       Value
1         4
2         1
3         0
4         0
```

Here is my SQL statement

```
update tableB set value = value + sq.total
from
( select id, count(*) as total from TableA group by id ) as sq
where sq.id = tableB.id;
```

With 3-10 Million entries in TableA, it is taking an awful amount of time. Is there a way I can optimize this query?

Comment: Do you have - for istance - a b-tree index on the first table index? Maybe it will help you.

Comment: Hi Don, I do have B-tree index on "id" in both tables.

Comment: That was my only idea... I don't know how you can improve running time... Sorry

Comment: Can you show us the execution plan? Ideally as `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and uploaded to http://explain.depesz.com/

Answer (score 1):

Do you need `tableB` to be initially populated? An `INSERT...SELECT` from `tableA` into an empty `tableB` (with no indexes on `tableB`) should be faster:

```
insert into tableb (id, value)
select id, count(*)
from tablea
group by id
```

and then add your indexes to `tableB` once the data is there.

Comment: I reduced the update time by reducing the size of column from integer to char. Thanks!